# Jquery datepicker icon position is incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid, datepicker

My calendar image is positioned below the text box of my datepicker. How can I solve this misalignment.

This is a screenshot of my screen: ! [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uifN.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uifN.jpg

See the jsfiddle here: jsfiddle.net/njiterry/yNw3C/8477

This is my jsp code:

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Country Visibility</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

    var mydata = [
        { Sel: true, Country : "Germany", Capital : "Berlin", Date: "05-09-2014"},
        { Sel: true, Country : "France", Capital : "Paris", Date: "05-09-2014" },
        { Sel: true, Country : "Cameroon", Capital : "Yaounde", Date: "06-09-2014" },
        { Sel: true, Country : "Gabon", Capital : "Libreville", Date: "06-09-2014" },
        { Sel: true, Country : "Holland", Capital : "Amsterdam", Date: "07-09-2014" },
        { Sel: true, Country : "Japan", Capital : "Tokyo", Date: "08-09-2014" },
        { Sel: true, Country : "Italy", Capital : "Rome" , Date: "09-09-2014"},
        { Sel: true, Country : "Spain", Capital : "Madrid" , Date: "09-09-2014"},
        { Sel: true, Country : "England", Capital : "London" , Date: "10-09-2014"},
        { Sel: true, Country : "US", Capital : "Washington D.C." , Date: "12-09-2014"}
    ];

    var grid = jQuery("#pays_grid");

    var initDateWithButton = function (elem) {
        if (/^\d+%$/.test(elem.style.width)) {
            // remove % from the searching toolbar
            elem.style.width = '';
        }
        // to be able to use 'showOn' option of datepicker in advance searching dialog
        // or in the editing we have to use setTimeout
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                showOn: 'button',
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,     
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
                buttonText: "Select date",            
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                    if (inst.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                         grid[0].triggerToolbar();
                    }
                    else {
                        // to refresh the filter
                        $(inst).trigger("change");
                    }
                }
            });

        $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").css({
            position: "relative",
            marginLeft: "1px",
            marginTop: "0px",
            });
        }, 100);
    };
    grid.jqGrid({ //set your grid id
    data: mydata, //insert data from the data object we created above
    datatype: 'local',
    height: 230,
    autoheight: true,
    width: 800,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [1, 5, 10],

    colNames:['Sel.','Id','Name', 'Date'], //define column names
    colModel:[
       {name: 'Sel', align: 'center', sortable: false, width: 25, search: false, editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', 
              editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false} },
       {name:'Country', index:'Country', key: true, width:50, align:'center'},
       {name:'Capital', index:'Capital', width:100, align:'center'},
       {name: 'Date', index: 'Date', align: 'center', width: 100}
    ], //define column models

    pager: '#pager', //set your pager div id
    sortname: 'Country', //the column according to which data is to be sorted; optional
    viewrecords: true, //if true, displays the total number of records, etc. as: "View X to Y out of Z” optional
    sortorder: "asc", //sort order; optional
    sortname: 'Country',
    shrinkToFit: true,
    forceFit: true,
    caption: "Country Overview", //title of grid
    loadComplete: function() { 
        grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'Date', {
            sorttype: 'date', editable: true,
                editoptions: { dataInit: initDateWithButton, size: 11 },
                searchoptions: {
                    sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
                    dataInit: initDateWithButton,
                  //  size: 8,          // for the advanced searching dialog
                   // attr: {size: 8}   // for the searching toolbar
                }
        });   
        grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autoSearch: true});
    }
    }).navGrid('#truck_grid_pager', {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true});


});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="pays_grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried looking at similar questions here on Stack Overflow but I can't get the trigger image to appear inline with the input.

Comment: Did you include the jQueryUI stylesheets?

Comment: @HelpNeeder: yes I did

Comment: please demonstrate it in jsfiddle please?

Comment: See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/njiterry/yNw3C/8477/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you should use

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input > input,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input > select,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input > img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/8486/

Comment: This really looks great. Thanks. Where should I add this css    code?

Comment: @Terry: You are welcome! You can add `<style type="text/css">...</style>` block with the CSS rules directly after `<link ... href=".../ui.jqgrid.css"/>`.

Comment: It works like a charm. I'm a newbie to jqgrid and I've been using your jqgrid answers. I am very impressed by your thorough technical knowledge but most importantly your patience and passion for helping others. Hats off man!

Comment: Do you have any idea why this jsfiddle does not workhttp://jsfiddle.net/njiterry/p9n8qq0x/5/. The jquery 1.6.2 version is not avaible so I use jquery 1.7.2. The javascript and css codes are the same as yours.

Comment: @Terry: You should include external resources with **full path** like `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css`, `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css`, `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js`, `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (see http://www.cdnjs.com/libraries/jqgrid). See http://jsfiddle.net/p9n8qq0x/6/

Comment: @Terry: If you are new in JSFiddle then I would recommend you to take a look in JSFiddle videos on youtube like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrWkRHSK6A8&list=UUcJJIbjeYCo9Myc2qTrR9HQ) for example.

Answer (score 0):

add display inline style to your text box that contains date
then adjust the margin-top of your date picker image to make it look nice and aligned with your text box.

check here: http://jsfiddle.net/saxenaabhi6/yNw3C/8479/

```
#gs_Date{
display:inline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting

```
 position='relative'
```

set

```
position='absolute'
```

and adjust top and left accordingly. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ey170t1z/1/

Answer (score 0):

in the CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
 vertical-align: top;
 height: 24px; /* the same of textbox */
}
```